# Two Tables with identical structures, different names, howto switch which is used at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, structuremap

I'd not planned for this as the requirement has only just emerged but Using Entity Framework we have pairs of tables (I'll call them Twins, A & B) with identical data structures but different names. This of course maps through via EF as pairs of objects of different types.

What I'd like to do is pretend I only have one table/object and have a switch somewhere (in the repository perhaps) that I can throw to get the data from the B group of tables rather than the A group.

I can't figure out whether there is a useful route using the repo, using structuremap and or polymorphism to enable this to work.

Al alternative might be to put the twin 'B' tables in a second database, and with the same name as their 'A' twin, if that would help at all ?

(Up until today I thought I had two different databases with no crossover and just needed to implement a connection string switch - turns out thats not the case as 80% of the tables are shared between the two states and its just the 3 or 4 that are twinned)

Comment: Three databases and corresponding connectionstrings. First two databases have the "twin" tables and the third has the "shared" tables.

Comment: There are FK's between the twin tables and the shared ones so I think that will break.

Comment: That will definately break. (Took a long shot hence I did not put it as an answer.)

Comment: Its an idea though...its got me thinking whether I can use 2nd DB, setup EF from the main one, and in the secondary swap out the shared tables for views of the tables in the main ? Probably not but I'll try it

Comment: What do you mean by identical structure? Thay have excatly the same field defenitions? What is the purpose of two different tables then? If so, than I suggest you to insert the difference flag inside the single table.

If they have crossing set of fields you can extract superclass and inherit it. 

Or you may extract interface and work with database only through repository, which will implement factory method.

Comment: I can't combine the tables for (sadly) political reasons. They do have exactly the same structure, and a flag would work, except that is not allowed. Has to be Database A and Database B (on different drives on the server, backed up to different tapes etc).

Comment: Can you explain more about how the factory methods would work - I can see how to swap DB using it, but not how to fetch some tables from one, and some from another while still allowing EF relationships to work, or to change the name of the table without breaking everything (or copying from one object type to another). I already put all through a repository but the objects are EF (not POCO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that creating two databases, generating the EF objects from the 1st, then in the 2nd dropping the common tables and replacing them with views back to the 1st with the same name works just fine. This then allows me to quite simply pick up the right connection string in the repository (although swapping repo's with structuremap would probably be neater).

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this through a combination of dependency injection and polymorphism.

Rather than operating directly on the entities (let's call them TwinA and TwinB), I would create the following types...

(pardon the name...not much contextual info in the question)

```
TwinModel (a projected type of the actual entities..hence view model)
```

Then, you would have...

```
ITwinRepository
TwinReposotoryImplA
TwinRepositoryImplB
```

Depending on the need, the correct Repository would be bound at runtime using structure map (through binding configuration).  The implementation differences would be to leverage one Entity set over another (TwinA or TwinB).

From a coding standpoint, you're still coding against ITwinRepository and operating on TwinModel, so consumers won't need be affected with future changes, should you decide to implement a TwinC table.  :O

Comment: (there's not much contextual info because the tables have names like Order and Class and Div which are themselves confusing! Twin is fine!) Meanwhile the issue is that I haden't seen this coming so I've coded against a Repo, but not used the TwinModel approach: an awful lot of re-code to do!